# Split files based on file content and pattern matching in Java

Tags: java, split

I have a below requirment:

```
 Rate: GBP
 12/01/1999,90.5911501,Validated
 .....
 .....
18/01/1999,90.954996,Validated
Rate: RMB
24/04/2008,132.2542,Validated
 .....
25/04/2008,132.2279,Validated
28/04/2008,131.69915,Validated
Rate: USD
21/11/11,-0.004419534,Validated
Rate: RMB
24/04/2008,132.2542,Validated
 .....
25/04/2008,132.2279,Validated
28/04/2008,131.69915,Validated
Rate: RMB
24/04/2008,132.2542,Validated
 .....
25/04/2008,132.2279,Validated
28/04/2008,131.69915,Validated
 Rate: GBP
 12/01/1999,90.5911501,Validated
 .....
 .....
 Rate: GBP
 12/01/1999,90.5911501,Validated
 .....
 .....
Rate: USD
21/11/11,-0.004419534,Validated
```

Here I have 3 "Rate: RMB" lines and the details of these untill the next "Rate" line.
My requirment is to split this file based on the "Rate: RMB" and create the output files with "Rate: RMB and its details. Output will be like below:

```
Rate: RMB
24/04/2008,132.2542,Validated
 .....
25/04/2008,132.2279,Validated
28/04/2008,131.69915,Validated
Rate: RMB
24/04/2008,132.2542,Validated
.....
25/04/2008,132.2279,Validated
28/04/2008,131.69915,Validated
Rate: RMB
24/04/2008,132.2542,Validated
 .....
25/04/2008,132.2279,Validated
28/04/2008,131.69915,Validated
```

I have tried with Java but not able to get the required output.

My code:

```
public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException
{

    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream( "C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\SplitFile\\InputTest.txt" );

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( fis ) );
    // System.out.println("11111");
    String s = "";
    String rate = "RMB";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int count = 1;
    // s=br.readLine();
    while ( ( s = br.readLine() ) != null )
    {
        if ( s.contains( "Rate" ) && s.substring( 6, 9 ).equals( rate ) )
        {

            if ( sb.length() != 0 )
            {
                System.out.println( count );
                File file = new File( "C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\SplitFile\\" + rate + "_" + count + ".txt" );
                PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter( file, "UTF-8" );
                writer.println( sb.toString() );
                writer.close();
                sb.delete( 0, sb.length() );
                count++;
            }
            continue;
            // System.out.println(name);
            // call read file

        }
        sb.append( s + "\n" );
        System.out.println( sb );
        // s=br.readLine();
    }

    br.close();
}
```

Comment: "but not able to get the required output." What output do you get?

Comment: I am getting three different files with name RMB_1, RMB_2, RMB_3 with all the details even with the details of "Rate: GBP"...

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to create a new file everytime the line `Rate: RMB` shows up and output everything underneath to that file, this code should do the trick for you:

```
public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception
{
    //get desktop location
    String location = System.getenv( "USERPROFILE" ) + "\\Desktop\\SplitFile\\";

    String regex = "^Rate..RMB";

    //get input file
    FileInputStream inputfile = new FileInputStream( location + "InputTest.txt" );
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( inputfile ) );

    int count = 0;
    String in = br.readLine();

    //if the file starts with the pattern, skip the first line
    if( Pattern.matches( regex, in ) )
        br.readLine();

    //create first output file
    File outfile = new File( location + "OutputFile_" + count + ".txt" );
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter( outfile );

    while( in != null )
    {
        //if pattern matches start a new file
        if( Pattern.matches( regex, in ) )
        {
            //close previous output
            pw.flush();
            pw.close();

            //create new output file
            outfile = new File( location + "OutputFile_" + count + ".txt" );
            pw = new PrintWriter( outfile );

            count++;
            in = br.readLine();
            continue;
        }

        //print to file
        pw.println( in );

        in = br.readLine();
    }

    //close final output
    pw.flush();
    pw.close();

    //close input
    br.close();
}
```

Comment: Hi Gelunox,

Thanks for your response ... But this code stuck in infinite loop and produces 0 byte files.

Comment: Hi Gelunox,

Now it is producing 3 files but it contains details of another Rate also and the file misses Rate: GBP header in each file.